# Could lower limit of a confidence interval be negative?

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, sas

I am using proc glimmix in sas to find the effect of the different urine tests taken with one diagnostic urine test, called urine LAM test. I use least squares mean to find the point estimates and confidence intervals, but I am getting negative values for the lower limits of my CI, how can I report the negative lower limits? For example:

```
LEUresults Estimate Standard Error DF t Value   Pr > |t| Alpha   Lower  Upper 
    0      0.1583      0.2157      43 0.73       0.4669  0.05  -0.2766 0.5932 
    1      0.1503      0.2414      43 0.62       0.5369  0.05  -0.3366 0.6371
```

And how can I interpret these results?

Comment: If only positive values make sense substantively, one interpretation is that you need a logarithmic link function.

Answer (score 6):

Yes ! The lower confidence bound can be negative. This is reflected by the p-values being quite large, around 0.5. This means that if the *true value* for the parameter is actually zero, then the probability of observing these data (or data more extreme) is around 0.5. A less technical explanation is that a plausible range for the estimated parameter may be zero or below.

Since you are modelling a variable that can’t be negative, this means that:

- the model is a very poor fit to the data, for example because the sample size is very small, and/or
- the model is mis-specified - for example in a case where we should be modelling the logarithm or the response.

Comment: It means primarily that the data model doesn’t fit, if the data can’t be negative.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I have added a paragraph saying this. Thanks :)

Comment: We ought to take some care concerning what we mean by "poor fit," lest the final conclusion be misunderstood: when the LCL is negative for a parameter that must be non-negative, conceivably the fit is excellent but the probability assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @whuber, thank you :), perhaps I should modify my last point along the line of "Since you are modelling a variable that can’t be negative, this means that either the model is a very poor fit to the data (for example because the sample size is very small), or the model fits well, but is mis-specified (for example in a case where the we should be modelling the logarithm of the response) ?

Comment: Right.  But it's not mutually exclusive: *both* situations could pertain.

Comment: @whuber Thanks again, I've made the edit :)

Comment: There's probably a better way I could have said it.  The sort of thing I was referring to was that when you use a method that assumes a symmetric data distribution you tend to get symmetric confidence intervals when on the data scale.  This leads to bad coverage when the data are really asymmetric, even including impossible values.